# How to fill in the nulls for the missing nodes. SQL

Tags: sql, hierarchy

I have data that have a hierachy level. If one leg of the hierarchy is shorter than the others, the last value must be carried down to the last level in my output.

Example: I have max 3 levels of data

```
                        AAB
                        /  \ 
                       AA    B  
                      /
                      A
```

I want to have output in which 'AA' and 'B' should be on the same level
but my output is giving me 'a' and 'b' on the same level.

Something like this

```
A-AA-AAB

B-AAB-NULL
```

But I want

```
A-AA-AAB

NULL-B-AAB
```

How to fill in the nulls for the missing nodes?

Comment: Please specify the engine you are using, provide DDL and sample data, and the desired result. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is your DBMS? and please provide the code you have tried.